# difference between operations and permissions on RBAC

Tags: rbac

I'm developing a generic user management system using role based access control(RBAC) were i couldn't distinguish between the operations table and the permissions table(that is after reading so many articles).

"*A subject can have multiple roles. A role can have multiple subjects. A role can have many permissions. A permission can be assigned to many roles. An operation can be assigned many permissions. **A permission can be assigned to many operations.***"

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

can anyone please give a simple example to distinguish between them?

Comment: I think this is a vague question as it depends on your underlying technology. Please clarify in what context you mean 'operations' and 'permissions' so you'll get a more accurate answers

Comment: this is written in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control
"
A subject can have multiple roles.
        A role can have multiple subjects.
        A role can have many permissions.
        A permission can be assigned to many roles.
        An operation can be assigned many permissions.
        A permission can be assigned to many operations."

Comment: As implied in the first answer below, your context or if you wish, the technology that you referred to, was based on the Wikipedia article :-) . That's fine. Since you marked that answer as accepted, i'll leave it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RBAC standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/) doesn't refer to operations, but only deals with users, roles, and permissions. I suppose that the operations you're referring to are part of the specific implementation you're using. They probably are the way resources are implemented in your solution.

A permission is what is needed to execute/access an resource. Permissions are assigned to roles, and resources require a set of permissions.

Let's take, for example, the case of a simple till management system. There are many users (the store's employees), and many roles, including `cashier operator`. That role gives the users one permission, `scan items`. Such permission is required by the operation `item.scan()`, and also by the operation `item.cancel()`.

Comment: please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control so that you can get what my question means

Comment: There are no contradictions between my answer and the Wikipedia page you are pointing to. Operations are a particular kind of resources, which are the "things" whose access is restricted. The example I provided uses operations as the restricted resources and illustrates the difference between an operation and a permission.

Comment: I did not find a free version of the RBAC spec online, but https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/sysadmin/role-based-access-control-nist-solution-1270 p. 7/8 states that roles and operations are different elements of the RBAC3 standard

Answer (score 1):

In RBAC a permission is a mapping between objects and operations.

For example:

customer123  <--- this is an object

read, write, update, delete   <--- these are operations

and these are the possible permissions:

customer123.read, customer123.write, customer123.update, customer123.delete

In RBAC, the permissions are then granted to roles.  So one role might be:

Users

and have been granted customer123.read

and another role might be:

Admins

which have been granted permissions customer123.write, customer123.update

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Permission - An approval of a mode of access to a resource. 
Resource - System object or operation that requires restricted access.